# Ambari Hadoop/Spark and Elasticsearch SSL Integration

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, elasticsearch, ambari

I have a Hadoop/Spark cluster setup via Ambari (​HDP -2.6.2.0). Now that I have my cluster running, I want to feed some data into it. We have an Elasticsearch cluster on premise (version 5.6). I want to setup the ES-Hadoop Connector (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/doc-sections.html) that Elastic provides so I can dump some data from Elastic to HDFS. 
I grabbed the ZIP file with the JARS and followed the directions on a blog post at CERN:

https://db-blog.web.cern.ch/blog/prasanth-kothuri/2016-05-integrating-hadoop-and-elasticsearch-%E2%80%93-part-2-%E2%80%93-writing-and-querying

So far, this seems reasonable, but I have some questions:

1. We have SSL/TLS setup on our Elasticsearch cluster, so when I perform a query, I obviously get an error using the example on the blog. What do I need to do on my Hadoop/Spark side and on the Elastic side to make this communication work?
2. I read that I need to add those JARS to the Spark classpath - is there a rule of thumb as to where i should put those on my cluster? I assume on of my Spark Client nodes, but I am not sure. Also, once i put them there, is there a way to add them to the classpath so that all of my nodes / client nodes have the same classpath? Maybe something in Ambari provides that?

Basically what I am looking for is to be able to preform a query to ES from Spark that triggers a job that tells ES to push "X" amount of data to my HDFS. Based on what I can read on the Elastic site, this is how I think it should work, but I am really confused by the documentation. It's lacking and has confused both me and my Elastic team. Can someone provide some clear directions or some clarity around what I need to do to set this up?

Comment: Regarding Spark, yes, Ambari manages your `spark-env.sh`. Regarding Elasticsearch, what specific errors are you getting? I assume you've misconfigured Spark to use SSL

Comment: I'm getting authentication errors, mostly due to the fact I believe that I'm not doing something right with username/pass and SSL... Is there some generic example when trying to query a stand-alone Elastic cluster from my Spark/Hadoop cluster? What I am looking for is - where do I put these JAR on my cluster? How do I set the CLASSPATH - once I have that done, how do I query an Elastic cluster with SSL? I assume I need to account for a cert or something... Are there any end-to-end examples floating around or that someone could provide?

Comment: Ideally, if writing a client application, you build what's called a shaded or uber jar. Forget modifying a classpath on the server - you don't want to mess any libraries up with conflicting versions. And if I'm reading this correctly, it tells you exactly what configurations  need to be set. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/security.html

Comment: SSL defaults to false, also. See options here. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html#_ssl

Comment: @cricket_007 - Our goal is to use Python for all of our machine learning and such - I did a quick Google search for "uber JAR" and it seems pretty basic - just a "super jar". I get the concept - the ES-Hadoop connector comes with a bunch of JAR files, one they refer to as the "uber" JAR, which contains all the code for all components of Hadoop/Spark - whereas they have smaller JARs for individual components. I get that. I guess my question is - what is the best way to get data from Elasticsearch to HDFS? Should I use this connector, or maybe just query Elastic when I need to?

Comment: @cricket_007 - Being a newbie at this, I guess I am also trying to figure out exactly how to do this - get data from ES to HDFS. I get that the connector can provide that, but I have no idea how to start going about doing that. The documentation isn't very helpful, but based on your initial comment, it sounds like I just need an account on ES, then I can specify all the options that ES mentions in their ES-Hadoop documentation, in my code on the Spark/Hadoop side. From there, I just query ES whenever I want more data? Does that sound right? If so, why do I need the connector?

Comment: For starters - you need at least a Spark connector to talk to ES. That doesn't require all the features of ES-Hadoop. Spark can very simply read/write data to both locations locations on it's own. While I have not personally done it - `SparkConf` would be a good starting point to set the properties mentioned in the documentation

Comment: If you need really focused Elastic answers, might be useful to hit up IRC, or https://discuss.elastic.co/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the project setup part of the question you can take a look at

https://github.com/zouzias/elasticsearch-spark-example

which a project template integrating elasticsearch with spark.

Comment: @Zousias - this is awsome. Is there a Python example, or only Scala? We are targeting Python for our development. Thanks!

Comment: @azdatasci No examples on PySpark that I know of.